# Correcting for serial correlation and after heteroskedasticity

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity

I have learnt in my econometrics class that after we are done with a time series model, we can use the DW test to check for first lag AR(1) errors, and later on use cochrane ocutt or prais to correct it. And only ensuring no serial correlation, can we proceed to test and correct for heteroskedasticity,

I have found out the equivalent packages on R to perform them, namely by passing in the regression model into the function.

Suppose my regmodel have serial correlation after doing DW test, and we wish to correct this:

```
    library(ocutt)
    cochrane.ocutt(regmodel)
```

This output a result with the corrected standard deviation. But if we were to proceed to heteroskedasticity test and remedy:
Both the cochrane ocutt and prais function do not output a model, which i cannot pass into bptest, followed by emulating the robust function of stata. (both requires a model as arguement)

```
    bptest(regmodel)
    library(foreign)
    library(sandwich)
    library(imtest)
    oeftest(regmodel, vcov = vcovHC(regmodel, "HC1")) #stata robust function
```

In the case that after correcting for serial correlation of AR(1), that the model may be heteroskedastic, I simply cannot continue on after ocutt and prais function since they do not return a model.

Can anyone guide me? Really appreciate the help guys.

Comment: I would use `gls` from package nlme and model autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity, but I might be missunderstanding since you don't show a model or diagnostics.